# GatsbyJS : Where to put the script to call the Hubspot API

Tags: gatsby, hubspot

I need to pull user information from Hubspot to my Gatsby site hosted on AWS Amplify. In their documentation, under NodeJS, they provide this bit of sample code :

```
var request = require("request");

var options = { method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/contact/vid/12627374/profile',
  qs: { hapikey: 'demo' }
}
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
});
```

I'm just not sure where that code should be so I can pull the data dynamically. Should it go under gatsby-browser.js ? Or do I need an extra module like Axios or Express ? Or does it go somewhere in my AWS install ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I got deals data using this in a component before the return statement:

```
export default function AppHub () {

    const [deals, setDeals] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
    
        fetch(`https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/objects/deals?hapikey=YOURKEYHERE&limit=100`,
        )
        .then(response => response.json()) // parse JSON from request
        .then(dealsapi => {
            console.log(dealsapi);
            setDeals(dealsapi.results);
        })
        .catch(console.error);
    }, []);
```